# How do I enable 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers for static files in Yesod?

Tags: file, haskell, static, yesod, phaser-framework

I'm using the scaffolded site and the static subdomain to serve my static files from.
The static files are being requested using explicit urls from Javascript games which I am using my yesod app to serve (written using the Phaser framework).

A sample error message from the Javascript console is this:

```
Phaser.Loader error loading file: player1_icon from URL http://example.com/static/games/mygame/images/player1/icon.png 
Image from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Some research shows me that adding the line `addHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"` in a handler function can solve this problem. However the static route does not use a handler function and so I don't know where I would put this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished by using a WAI middleware that adds this header. That middleware would be added in your `Application` module. There are a number of middlewares in the wai-extra package that can be used as an example of how to do this.

More generally: this is probably a feature worth building into yesod-static itself. Can you open up a Github issue about it?

Comment: Maybe [wai-cors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors) might be of some use here.